# How to use this library it has only .java files in it

Tags: java

I don't want to use any building tools or IDE i want to know how this all works
and if anyone has any source where i can learn how to use the compiler and stuff like this pleas link them
i thought of using class path but there are so many folders and i have seen it been used only in jars files not in
.java files or should i compile them all

```
├── convertVidToAudio.java <= this is my file 
└── velvet-video
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── gradle
    │   └── wrapper
    │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
    │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
    ├── gradlew
    ├── gradlew.bat
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── LICENSE.Apache-2.0
    ├── LICENSE.GPL-3.0
    ├── README.md
    └── src
        ├── example
        │   └── java
        │       └── com
        │           └── zakgof
        │               └── velvetvideo
        │                   └── example
        │                       ├── AudioPlayback.java
        │                       ├── ExtractAndTranscodeAudio.java
        │                       ├── ImagesToVideoAndBack.java
        │                       ├── RemuxVideo.java
        │                       ├── ScreenCaptureToVideo.java
        │                       ├── TranscodeVideoWithTimingEffects.java
        │                       └── Util.java
        ├── main
        │   └── java
        │       └── com
        │           └── zakgof
        │               └── velvetvideo
        │                   ├── Direction.java
        │                   ├── IAudioDecoderStream.java
        │                   ├── IAudioEncoderBuilder.java
        │                   ├── IAudioEncoderStream.java
        │                   ├── IAudioFrame.java
        │                   ├── IAudioStreamProperties.java
        │                   ├── IContainerProperties.java
        │                   ├── IDecodedPacket.java
        │                   ├── IDecoderStream.java
        │                   ├── IDemuxer.java
        │                   ├── IEncoderBuilder.java
        │                   ├── impl
        │                   │   ├── AbstractEncoderBuilderImpl.java
        │                   │   ├── AudioEncoderBuilderImpl.java
        │                   │   ├── AudioStreamPropertiesImpl.java
        │                   │   ├── Dummy.java
        │                   │   ├── FileSeekableInput.java
        │                   │   ├── FileSeekableOutput.java
        │                   │   ├── jnr
        │                   │   │   ├── AVCodecContext.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVCodec.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVCodecParameters.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVDictionaryEntry.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVFormatContext.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVFrame.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVInputFormat.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVIOContext.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVOption.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVOutputFormat.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVPacket.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVPixelFormat.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVRational.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVSampleFormat.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AVStream.java
        │                   │   │   ├── LibAVCodec.java
        │                   │   │   ├── LibAVFilter.java
        │                   │   │   ├── LibAVFormat.java
        │                   │   │   ├── LibAVUtil.java
        │                   │   │   ├── LibSwResample.java
        │                   │   │   ├── LibSwScale.java
        │                   │   │   └── SwsContext.java
        │                   │   ├── JNRHelper.java
        │                   │   ├── middle
        │                   │   │   ├── AudioFrameHolder.java
        │                   │   │   ├── AudioFrameImpl.java
        │                   │   │   ├── BestMatchingAudioFormatConvertor.java
        │                   │   │   ├── Feeder.java
        │                   │   │   ├── Filters.java
        │                   │   │   ├── IFrameHolder.java
        │                   │   │   ├── VideoFrameHolder.java
        │                   │   │   └── VideoFrameImpl.java
        │                   │   ├── RemuxerBuilderImpl.java
        │                   │   ├── VelvetVideoLib.java
        │                   │   └── VideoEncoderBuilderImpl.java
        │                   ├── IMuxerBuilder.java
        │                   ├── IMuxer.java
        │                   ├── IRawPacket.java
        │                   ├── IRemuxerBuilder.java
        │                   ├── IRemuxerStream.java
        │                   ├── ISeekableInput.java
        │                   ├── ISeekableOutput.java
        │                   ├── IVelvetVideoLib.java
        │                   ├── IVideoDecoderStream.java
        │                   ├── IVideoEncoderBuilder.java
        │                   ├── IVideoEncoderStream.java
        │                   ├── IVideoFrame.java
        │                   ├── IVideoStreamProperties.java
        │                   ├── MediaType.java
        │                   ├── MemSeekableFile.java
        │                   └── VelvetVideoException.java
        └── test
            └── java
                └── com
                    └── zakgof
                        └── velvetvideo
                            ├── AudioTest.java
                            ├── AudioUtil.java
                            ├── FilterTest.java
                            ├── FreeCodecSuite.java
                            ├── FreeEncodeDecodeTest.java
                            ├── FullEncodeDecodeTest.java
                            ├── GenericEncodeDecodeTest.java
                            ├── MetadataTest.java
                            ├── RawTest.java
                            ├── SeekableOutputTest.java
                            ├── SeekTest.java
                            ├── VarTimingTest.java
                            └── VelvetVideoTest.java
```

Comment: *should i compile them all* you should. this library clearly uses gradle as the build tool. if you refuse to use gradle to build it, you're likely to have a bad time.

Comment: The number of files is orthogonal to how to do it. If you don't want to use Gradle you will need to manually resolve all the transitive dependencies, e.g., find all the top-level dependencies, then find the dependencies of those dependencies, then find the dependencies of *those* dependencies, until there are no dependencies left. This is likely to be... annoying. OTOH, if you visit [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.zakgof/velvet-video/0.5.1) you can see it claims no compile time deps, just runtime, so you may only have to deal w/ the runtime deps.

Comment: Oh except that it's using Gradle plugins as well, which is another layer of fun (and one of them is Lombok, so byte-code manipulation). Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two very different things to do depending on what your goal is:

1. if your goal is just to *use* the library, then use the build system they use (in this case gradle) to build a jar file and use that. The build system exists **precisely** with this goal in mind and trying to avoid using it for this goal is like insisting on screwing in a screw without using a screwdriver.
2. if you want to learn how the library is supposed to be compiled, then learn the build system that they use and read its configurations files (in this case build.gradle) and interpret it accordingly.

As you see in both cases you'll have to get at least *some* familiarity with the build system, because sufficiently complex software is more than just a bunch of source files.

First of all almost all software will have some dependencies. The build system usually takes care of grabbing the appropriate dependencies. And the dependencies of dependencies (called transitive dependencies).

Second, *some* (but definitely not all) software will require some auxiliary steps for building, such as converting some DSL files into generated code (parsers/lexers are a common sample, but protobuf is another example).

Third, as Dave Newton suggested in the comments, some software further complicates matters by changing the actual compilation steps themselves in a way that's not easily reproduced using just the JDK command-line tools (specifically things like the Lombok Gradle Plugin).

Comment: okay so there are no way to using building tools

Comment: @MegaPlayers: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: yeah me to i was trying to say that there is no way of getting around building tools

Comment: You might get around using them once you understand what exactly they do. But most people who get to know them well enough agree that they are a useful tool and want to continue using them (and some decide they want to build a better one). So while they are not strictly "necessary", you need to understand them to be able to decide when you don't need them.

Comment: Nit: you mean 'transitive' dependencies, not 'transient' (which means temporary, intermittent, or varying/changing)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: absolutely, you're right. Feel free to edit the next time you see such a typo ;-)